# Brent's Method convergence criteria

Tags: root-systems, nonlinear-analysis, model-categories, numerical-calculus

I am using Brent's method to solve the BEM equations for a wind turbine model. I have run into a scenario where Brent's method has converged i.e., abs(m) is below set tolerance of 1e-8 but the value of the function f(root) = 5000. Can one then say that Brent's method failed to converge to a reasonable solution? What could be the reason for the function behaving like this?

[Value of the function i.e., f(root)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb5rI.png)
[Stop criteria i.e., abs(m)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5JPM.png)

The same case when tried with fixed point iteration scheme converges below 1e-8. I was under the impression that Brent's method has the property of guaranteed convergence at a super-linear rate and hence was a better root-finding method than fixed-point iteration. However, it seems that it may not be so straight forward.

Comment: You have not provided any decription for your graphs. As such they are nothing more than squiggly lines, devoid of meaning. There are several possible reasons that $f(r) = 5000$, including (1) erroneous implementation of Brent's method (2) discontinuous or near discontinuous $f$ (3) $5000$ is actually negligibly small with respect to the total variation of $f$.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. The first graph represents the value of f(r) and the second graph corresponds to the other iteration stop criterion abs(m)<tol.

Comment: Anyways my question was basically "When can one say the iteration converged successfully for Brent's method"? There are two conditions and if either is satisfied Brent loop terminates. These conditions are
abs(m) < tolerance or f(b) = 0.0 according to ALGOL 60
While this is self explanatory my question is what happens in a specific case where abs(m) is less than set tolerance but f(b) i.e., f(root) = 5000 (or some value nowhere close to zero). Would this case still be considered as "successfully converged"?.

Comment: The function being evaluated is
f(ɸ) = sinɸ / (1-a(ɸ))  -  cosɸ*(1-k(ɸ));
The implementation of Brent is taken from ALGOL 60 procedure 'zero'. It is an inbuilt function in Modelica called 'solveOneNonlinearEquation' solver but basically uses Brent's method to find the root of a function

Comment: Any idea what happens when both the conditions abs(m) < tolerance and fb = 0.0 are not true? Would there be an inbuilt maximum iteration criteria to stop the while loop like in fixed-point iteration scheme?

Comment: If that is your function, then my reason #2 is the answer. Your function swings WILDLY back and forth. You can be a tiny distance from a root (apparently you have many, many roots) and the function has a vastly different value. Brent's method probably converged to a root just fine (though with this behavior, straight bisections would likely be a little faster, since that doesnt waste time trying to predict the clearly unpredictible). But even the tiny tolerence you allow puts the function in a vastly different value.

Comment: The funcdtions $a(\phi)$ and $k(\phi)$ would have to be mighty strange to make $$\frac{\sin\phi}{1-a(\phi)} - (1-k(\phi))\cos\phi$$ look like that graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you start with two positions of opposite sign, Brent's method will always converge to a root. Contrary to your understanding, it is not guaranteed to be superlinear in convergence. It tries to be, but if the function is bad, it may be slightly slower than the bisection method (the function of your graph is really bad). This is because every time it tries to estimate a root location, the wild swings of the function make that estimate garbage, forcing it to resort to a bisection step.

So you end up with converging by bisection anyway, but spending a lot of wasted effort trying to make predictions that don't work.

Because Brent's method falls back on bisection, you are guaranteed it will converge. But note that its works by shrinking an interval $[a_n, b_n]$ with $f(a_n)f(b_n) < 0$. With each step, it shrinks that interval to be at most half the previous interval. While it does check to see if it happened to land exactly on a root, its normal stop criterion is $|a_n - b_n| < \text{tolerance}$. That tells you that there is a root somewhere between $a_n$ and $b_n$.

The tolerance is how much error you can accept in *the location of the root*, not in the value of $f$ at the root. The method does not guarantee a size limit for $f(r)$ where $r$ is the value it returns. Instead, it guarantees that $r$ is within your tolerance value of an actual root of the function.

Comment: A small question regarding root find methods. Is it possible for two root finding methods say fixed point iteration and Brent's method to converge to two completely different values for the same function? If yes, then which value is the true root or are both of them roots to the function? In essence, if a function has multiple roots, how can one say which root will be found?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fixed point interation", but if there is more than one root then yes it is possible for different methods to converge to different roots (your graph has a multitude of roots in each of those clumps). With interval-based methods like bisection and Brent's, all you can be sure of is that they will converge to *a* root within the starting interval, so you can get the root you want by excluding all other roots from that interval. With non-interval based methods, you have to know enough about the function to select the right starting point.

Comment: By fixed point iteration, I mean the general iterative scheme of finding the (n+1)th value using nth value and iterating until the value converges to set tolerance (essentially non-interval based method which needs a starting point). Thank you for your valuable insight.

Comment: @sairam.nagareddy - that actually describes *every* approximation scheme. For interval based schemes, the "value" is the pair of numbers defining the interval. Some schemes use even more values. But when the scheme converges, all the values will converge to a single number.

Comment: Is it possible for Brent's method to skip a root as it falls back on bisection? What I mean is, is it possible for Brent's method to not able to find a certain root when there are multiple roots?

Comment: It's possible for *any* root finding scheme to "skip a root" if there are multiple roots in the range where you are seeking. They do not have the ability to distinguish between roots built-in. They are designed to find **a** root, not the particular root you are after. If you are after a particular root, you have to take special steps to keep them from converging to another. Those steps are something you have to figure out based on what you know. They are not built into the generic root finding algorithm.